# Restrict Visual Studio 2019 to allow only latin characters in code

Tags: visual-studio-2019, character-set

How can I restrict Visual Studio 2019 to allow only latin characters in identifiers? That means, I want method names and variable names to be in latin characters, and not for example in greek characters. The following code compiles in Visual Studio 2019:

```
Module Module1

    Private Sub MethodLatin()
        Console.WriteLine("MethodLatin")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ΜέθοδοςΕλληνική()
        Dim αβγ = "ΜέθοδοςΕλληνική"
        Console.WriteLine(αβγ)
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        MethodLatin()
        ΜέθοδοςΕλληνική()
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

I would like to forbid to write the second method (ΜέθοδοςΕλληνική) in greek characters. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything to do this. In theory, you should be able to dictate this via the code-style or formatting rule options, but I don't see a setting for Latin only names: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options?view=vs-2019

Comment: That's legal code so VS won't forbid it by any option. You could write a custom analyzer to flag them.

Comment: Allowing non-latin characters in identifiers, makes the code unreadable in US and probably other regional settings. As an improvement to Visual Studio, I propose a setting that allows non-latin characters in identifiers.